# Is there any way to block all video files from opening in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, video

I want to temporarily block video files from opening on windows 7. Is there any way for that

Comment: What - blocking videos from within a browser, or just blocking all videos from being played from files that you click on on your hard drive?

Comment: I mean files on  hard drive

Comment: What is the purpose: protecting certain group of files or preventing users from abusing the machine for entertainment?

Comment: It might be easier to prevent video players from opening than certain files from being accessed.

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing you can do is unassociate the video files.

Comment: How does one do this? There are also problems to this approach as he only wants it temporary, and you could easy do `open with` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to protect files on a hard drive.  Encrypt them with something like [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/).  Files cannot be read = files that cannot be played.